# How can I specify arrow tips as an option in TikZcd

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd

I am using TikZcd to make a number of diagrams. I want some of these to use a circle as an arrowhead. However, if I write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[>=Circle]
A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & B \arrow[d] \\
C \arrow[r] & D
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

The arrowheads are just the default. How can I change the arrowheads in just this diagram?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! For instance, `begin{tikzcd}[arrows=-stealth]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arrows type `Circle` you need to load `arrows.meta` library and than define arrows style for example as `every arrow/.append style = {-{Circle[scale=0.5]} }`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzcd}[%sep=large,
every arrow/.append style = {-{Circle[scale=0.5]} }
                ]
A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & B \arrow[d] \\
C \arrow[r] & D
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]